# find Min number from blocks of given list

Tags: algorithm

you are given string of digits, a value x and N. you have to divide that string in ((i-1)*x+1,min(i*x)) parts.

for example a String is ="1234567891" and x=5,N=10 then

there will be 2 partition of string since x=5 
[12345] end [67891]

you have to find kth min number from these combinations. for example k=3 then ans should be 17

combination will happen like every digit from 1st partition will concatenate with other partition digits

so if there were three partition for string 123456789 then it could be like

[123][456][789]

and if k=3 then ans would be 149

Comment: Please refine your question. There are unexplained variables and magic numbers in it, e.g. i, ix, k, 17. It is also unclear what you really intend to do.

Comment: Is a number `N` always divided by a number `x` without a remainder?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then for `x=5`, `N=10`, string is `1234567891` when all combinations in sorted order are 11, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 26, 27, 28, 29, 31...

**If `N` is divided `x` without remainder then we have next solution:**

- sort all digits in each part (get `12345` and `16789`);
- convert `k-1` to `x` number system with `N/x` numbers as array `a` (`2` in `5` number system is `[2]`, add zeroes to `N/x=2` numbers and get `a=[0,2]`);
- get `a_i` digit (0-index) from `i` part for each part (`0`-index from `12345` is `1`, `2`-index from `16789` is `7`);
- concat all digits and get answer is `17`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I further want to clarify. let's say we have string str="123456789" and clearly length of string N=9 and x =3 so  we will be having 3 lists [123],[456],[789] and then if K=3 ans should be 149 so according to your logic it will work by getting number system of 2 in 3 which is 2 and adding two 0's in beginning. so 0 0 and 2 then ans will be 149.  Thanks I guess it will work